# While loop with Sockets and Threads does not close when expected

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I am trying to create a method where a server would run a while loop waiting for enough clients to join. When clients send a string containing "JOIN", the server should create a new thread, update the number of clients connected and run the while loop again. The issue I have is that when I get the client to join, my server updates the number of clients joined, but does not close the loop to check the while statement again and run the loop accordingly.

I am not really sure why it is happening. I have tried to somehow return the run() method of the thread created, but that seems to have no effect on the loop.

```
public void handleConnection()throws IOException{
    while(participants.size() < parts){
        System.out.println("Current amount of participants joined: " + participants.size() + " out of " + parts);
        s = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("New client connection attempt from port " + s.getPort());

        CoordinatorThread thread = new CoordinatorThread(s);
        //System.out.println("Thread created");
        synchronized (participantThreads){
            participantThreads.put(thread, s.getPort());
        }
        //System.out.println("Starting thread");
        thread.start();
    }

    System.out.println("All participants joined:");
    int no = 1;
    for(int i : participants){
        System.out.println(no + ") " + i);
        no++;
    }
}


public class CoordinatorThread extends Thread{
    private PrintWriter pr;
    private InputStreamReader in;
    private BufferedReader bf;
    private Socket socket;
    private int pport;
    //private boolean joined = false;

    public CoordinatorThread(Socket s) throws IOException {
        socket = s;
        in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        bf = new BufferedReader(in);
        pr = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

    }

    public void run(){
        String str = null;
        try {
            str = bf.readLine();
            System.out.println("Str: " + str);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(str != null && str.contains("JOIN")){
            System.out.println("Not null and contains JOIN");
            String[] splitStr = str.split(" ");
            pport = Integer.parseInt(splitStr[1]);
            participants.add(pport);
            pr.println(pport + " join accepted");
            pr.flush();
            System.out.println("COORD: A new participant has joined - " + pport + " / " + socket.getPort()+"\n" +
                    "total participants: " + participants.size());
        }

    }
}
```

The participant class is simply client class with a socket that connects to the coordinator and sends "JOIN " to join the server.

Comment: You could use a [CountdownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to handle the countdown of clients.

Comment: @fpezzini that could work, but I want to avoid setting a time window for clients to join. I want the program to respond to connections rather than make clients try to fit the open window.

Comment: A Countdown is not a timer. You create it specifying how many to count down, say 3 clients. Every time a client connects you decrement. Once it reaches 0 you can then take action.